# Empty array with length different from zero. Can you explain me this?

Tags: javascript

```
var myNumb = 5;
var myArr = Array(myNumb);
console.log(myArr.length); // 5
console.log(myArr[0]) // undefined, as well as for myArr[1] myArr[2] myArr[3] myArr[4]
```

These lines create an array `myArray` that has a length of 5, but it's also said "an empty array", in fact `myArr[0]` is `undefined`, for example.

I can't understand how is possible to have an empty array with a length different from zero. If the array has not items, how can it have a length different from zero?

Comment: The length isn't calculated when you "get" it. It's just a property of the array, updated when you add / remove items, or when you create the array.

Comment: What value do you *expect* `myArr[0]` to have?  *Why?*

Answer (score 2):

Positions in an array are still there even if they have no value, they are empty. Say you have the following code:

```
var myArray = new Array(5);
myArray[4] = 'Hello';
```

Do you expect `'Hello'` to be in position 0 or 4? The answer is, of course, 4. The array has a length of 5, and even if indices 0 to 3 are empty, index 4 has a value.

As per MDN documentation, using the Array constructor yields the following:

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer
>   between 0 and (2^32)-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array
>   with its length property set to that number (**Note:** this implies an
>   array of `arrayLength` empty slots, not slots with actual undefined
>   values). If the argument is any other number, a `RangeError` exception
>   is thrown.

[JavaScript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: `undefined`? Not quite. They have _no value_.